# Eclipse Plugin does not work in FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder Standalone

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, plugins, flash-builder, flexbuilder

created an Eclipse plugin that contributes to the UI by

- a new project wizard
- a new menu in the context menu of projects in the Package Explorer
- a new project nature + builder
- a new preference page for the plugin

The plugin works fine when installed in a normal Eclipse instance with Flex/Flashbuilder as plugin.

The problem now is, that the plugin never gets activated when i install it in a Flex/Flashbuilder Standalone instance. Neither of the features described above is available.

I even have no idea how to debug this, error-log (workspace/.metadata/.log) the following message appears, (but i dont think it is related to the problem)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2009-07-20 17:51:17.984
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2009-07-20 17:51:17.984
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource':
HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource, handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler),
expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1c45731),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1c45731)),sourcePriority=16640)
HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource,
handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler),
expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1c45731),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1c45731)),sourcePriority=16640)
```

In the "Configuration Details" my feature doesn't show up in the `*** Features: section` and my plugin doesn't show up in the `*** Plugin-in Registry: section`.
But they appear under `Configured features` and `Configured plug-ins`.

Starting FlashBuilder with -clean didn't solve the problem.
(the start command is now "C:\Programme\Adobe\Flash Builder Beta\Gumbo.exe" -clean)

My plugin depends on

```
org.eclipse.ui,
org.eclipse.core.runtime,
org.eclipse.core.resources,
com.adobe.flexbuilder.project
com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui
com.adobe.flexbuilder.ui
```

All of these should be available, as i see it. (and an error should be generated if they were not, i hope)

Comment: Are the dependencies of your plug-ins and features satisfied in the standalone distribution?  
Other than that, in mysterious cases like this I always recommend starting Eclipse with the -clean argument to force Equinox to flush its cache and re-read the bundle information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i updated my question to include more informations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved "!MESSAGE Conflict" in log by editing file:

```
 Adobe Flash Builder 4\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone_4.0.1.277662\plugin.xml
```

In this file next tag is unnecessary:

```
<actionSet
    description="%standaloneDescriptionNavigationActions"
    id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate"
    label="%standalone.navigate.flex.navigation"
    visible="true">
     <action
           definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource"
           label="%OpenWorkspaceFileAction.label"
           helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.open_workspace_file_action_context"
           class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler"
           menubarPath="navigate/open.ext2"
           id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate.OpenWorkspaceFile">
     </action>
  </actionSet>
```

This tag leads to duplicated "Open resource..." menu item. This duplication raises a conflict.
Comment it (or remove) and start flash builder with clean option:

```
FlashBUilder.exe -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem of the standalone flexbuilder version. We tried to install subversive in flexbuilder and it also didn't work correct.