# Eclipse + Flex Builder: keyboard shortcuts for “open resource” stopped working?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder, flash-builder

I upgraded from Eclipse 3.4.2 + Flex Builder 3.5 to Eclipse Eclise 3.5.1 + Flash Builder 4.1, and for some reason keyboard shortcuts for “open resource” just stopped working.

I can click “Navigate -> Open Resource” without any problems, but no matter what I change it to, the keyboard shortcut doesn't work.

The only strange thing is that there are two “Open Resource” entries in the “Navigate” menu (see below)… But both open up the correct window when I click them.

[image]

Also note: I only have one plugin, viPlugin, installed… But I still get this problem after removing it.

So, how can I fix this?

**Edit**: Checking the log, I see this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2011-02-03 15:15:01.970
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2011-02-03 15:15:01.970
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource':
HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource,
        handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler),
        expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.NavigateActionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1540a77),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1540a77)),sourcePriority=16640)
HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource,
        handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler),
        expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1540a77),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1540a77)),sourcePriority=16640)
```

Comment: I've temporarily hacked around this problem by aliasing cmd+shift+r to "open type"… But that's suboptimal.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other application capturing the key events? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725587/ctrl-shift-r-is-not-working-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two parties are registering a command under the same key binding. I would guess that the problem is in the new Flash Builder plugin and you should report this to Adobe. In the meantime, here are some things to try...

1. Switch to another perspective. These sort of problems can be specific to the perspective you are in.
2. Under Preferences -> General Key, type "Open Resource" in the filter box. You should see the two commands listed. Remove the key binding from one of them. Close the dialog and try. If nothing happens, you probably removed the key binding from the wrong one. Go back to the dialog and swap the one that you leave.

Comment: Hrm… Tried that, but it didn't work: https://skitch.com/wolever/rcxg8/preferences

Comment: Also worth noting: when I took that screen shot, I had cmd+shift+r bound to “open type”, but that conflict doesn't show up in the “conflicts”.

Comment: Nope, switching perspectives and editors doesn't seem to help either =\

Comment: Also, I did notice an error in the error log. See the edited question.

Comment: I recommend reporting this problem to Adobe. I don't believe there is anything you can do about this as a user. The FlexBuilder plugin is registering a conflicting handler for a command already registered by Eclipse. This cannot be resolved by changing key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

there's a walkaround.

edit {eclipse}\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone_{VERSION}\plugin.xml

Comment out this part:

```
  <actionSet
        description="%standaloneDescriptionNavigationActions"
        id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate"
        label="%standalone.navigate.flex.navigation"
        visible="true">
     <action
           definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource"
           label="%OpenWorkspaceFileAction.label"
           helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.open_workspace_file_action_context"
           class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler"
           menubarPath="navigate/open.ext2"
           id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate.OpenWorkspaceFile">
     </action>              
  </actionSet>
```

then restart eclipse with clean:

```
eclipse.exe - clean
```

please refer to this post:
[Eclipse Plugin does not work in FlashBuilder/FlexBuilder Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153668/eclipse-plugin-does-not-work-in-flashbuilder-flexbuilder-standalone)