# Ctrl + Shift + R is not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

We all know that we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to search any file in the workspace.
But today, I surprisingly found out that it is not working anymore.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> are working though.

I believe I am missing a setting somewhere possibly in Window -> Customise Perspective menu. Not sure what is it exactly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just realized this morning that I have a screen capture tool called Snagit installed which uses the same key combination to start capture.

When I closed Snagit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is back in action in Eclipse.

But not sure why the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> did not even open Snagit last week when I tied so hard. May be Snagit was not running last week!

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Did you replace SnagIt, close it, or just change its hotkeys?

Comment: I just closed SnagIt application at that time to get going. Eventually my trail version got expired and hence I uninstalled SnagIt.

Comment: I've just experienced the exact same problem this morning. I now just need to raise a ticket to get Snagit uninstalled from my machine then wait for about 20 days for it to be actioned. It's a brave new world we live in with everything being locked down :)

Comment: I found UISpy was also creates trouble for the ctrl+shift+R hotkey

Comment: N.B. Snagit uses `Ctrl + Shift  + R` for `Repeat Last Capture`. Change in Snagit Tools and then exit Snagit in order for `Ctrl + Shift + R` to work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue with Eclipse, and in my case the issue was "Samsung Magician" running at the same time. As soon as I terminated it, Eclipse picked up the shortcut again ...

Comment: Somehow, Samsung Magician disables this shortcut; it doesn't work in other programs either. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Fixed it for me on chrome. Thank you

Comment: This saved my day. Fix for my Ctrl+W on Chrome And Eclipse shortcut as well. Any idea to make Samsung Magician works with other apps' shortcut again?

Comment: After upgrading to version 8.0.1 of Magician, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in Eclipse. And it occured when I reopened my Workspace. In my case, when I re-started eclipse, the workspace opened in J2EE perspective by default. Ctrl+Shift+R does not work in this perspective. I changed my perspective to 'Java' and it started working again.

Maybe you have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

A window manager application [4tray Minimizer](http://www.4t-niagara.com/tray.html) interferes with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> by default.

Comment: I am not using 4tray Minimizer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that @Juuso. I would never came up with an idea that 4tray might block Ctrl + Shift + R (commonly used in ReSharper as well).

Answer (score 2):

If it is Mac then you may have to use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any AddOns installed? check if any of these overrites the Key combination and change it if though. If this doesnt help then check the [Eclipse settings](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action?).

Comment: I just have SVN and Ivy plug-ins.

Comment: check the configurations if any of them uses the Ctrl + Shift + R. if not check the ones of eclipse maby its the combination was changed, check this site: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F

Comment: I could see it at Window > Preferences > General > Editor > Keys page.
I could also see it is having same category and when values like Ctrl Shift H and Ctrl Shift T. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

we can able to resolve the issue.

Please follow [this link](http://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/snagit_ctrl_shift_r).

There is a [video](http://screencast.com/t/ZoRbzhtHOXk7) on how to modify the global short cut keys.

Go to SnagIt -> Tools -> Program Preferences modify the keyboard short cut key combination 
as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other plug-in also defines that key binding. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to list all available shortcuts on the current context to check the whether someone conflicts with the JDT's.

Comment: Tried this too. The opened list of all shortcuts lists Ctrl+Shift+R against Open Resource.

Comment: Could you find any error information in the 'Error log' view after typing ctrl+shift+l?

Comment: I shall try and let you know soon.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and managed to resolve it by following steps:

Open or search Snagit 9.

Click `Tools > Program Preferences`

Un-check or remove check boxes under 'Repeat last capture hotkey' and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

If the conflict is with Snagit setting global hotkey, then change this in Snagit.

Tools>Program Preferences> Hotkeys and change default key combination to something else that doesn't conflict (e.g. just check Alt)

Answer (score 0):

Or try change hotkey on layout switch, I my case after using Windows many year I set it for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and it's why I can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in Eclipse. When I'm turning to  Caps Lock all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not with your key combination, there is another issue which will bring up the Open Resources view but will not display any results when you type the resource name you are looking for. This happens especially when your projects are organized into eclipse working sets.

Bring up the open Resources view with your key combination or using the menu bar. On the right-hand-side just below the close view icon (x) there is a small icon with a triangle. Click this icon and then click on "select working set". This will bring up the "select working set" view. In this view select the "Windows Working Sets". Then select OK.