# Eclipse doesn't do any hyperlinks or at least highlight the syntax of some of the *.h files and *.S

Tags: c, eclipse, assembly

I'm using Eclipse CDT ( helios ).
The syntax highlighting is missing When I open some , and not all, *.h files in a project.
and Sometimes the syntax highlighting is activated and navigation using hyperlinks isn't activated.

I can't even use ( shift + ctrl + T ) to navigate to other elements when the Editor is on some of the *.h files.

The same exact thing happens for *.S files.

## edit

Everything ( syntax highlighting, hyperlinks, and shift+ctrl+T ) is working correctly with *.cpp files.

Comment: Are you sure opening the .h file by C/C++ editor? Try right click on the .h file, choose 'open with' - 'C/C++ Editor'

Comment: Although the default in the 'File Associations' is opening *.h file using C/C++ Editor, sometimes it just doesn't. Doing 'open with' only solves the issue related to 'Syntax Highlighting', It doesn't solve the navigation issue.

Comment: Might the key be hooked by system shortcut. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725587/ctrl-shift-r-is-not-working-in-eclipse/5783895#5783895

Comment: This problem only happens in some *.h and *.c files. Other files are working just fine ( like *.cpp files ), and thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that CDT isn't configured to abort syntax highlighting in big files (see CDT configuration). It is enabled by default...