# Keyboard Shortcut doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a very weird problem with my Eclipse (Helios).

All my shortcuts work fine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a type for example), but only one doesn't work.

The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open a resource doesn't work. I this shortcut very often and it's a big problem it doesn't work.

I don't have any custom shortcut, all are the default shortcut.
In the key menu, this shortcut is well mapped.

Someone knows how to repair this?

Comment: Where is the log file for eclipse ?

Comment: The log file is located at <workspace>\.metadata\.log file. But first you should look in the 'Error log' view in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I have nothing in log file and in the Error log view

Comment: it looks like duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725587/ctrl-shift-r-is-not-working-in-eclipse

Comment: Thanks, I have installed ramboost and it use this shortcut :(

Comment: @Kiva - pls put that as the answer and write exactly what you have done in ramboost so that it can help others. see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5783895/728610

Comment: Maybe isn't because of the mapping. Check the 'When' select box. Examples 'in Windows / editing java / editing jsp...'