# Flex/Flash Builder stand alone has a duplicate "Open Resource" menu

Tags: flexbuilder, flash-builder

I've seen an issue a few different installations whereby the `Open Resoure` menu open in `Navigate` appears twice, which wouldn't be a problem if it didn't disable the `CTRL+SHIFT+R` shortcut to it.

I've seen it affect both Flex Builder 3 and Flash Builder 4, but it only seems to affect the standalone version when it is installed *after* the plugin version. Re-installation doesn't seem to help.

*NOTE: I'm posting this with the intent of self-answering*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently spotted [the answer posted by Kammerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153668/eclipse-plugin-does-not-work-in-flashbuilder-flexbuilder-standalone/3583224#3583224) on a related question, but it doesn't appear will in search results. I'm reproducing the solution here, but please vote up the original answer if this answer helped.

1. Open `%FLEX_BUILDER_HOME%\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone_3.0.214193\plugin.xml`

   - %FLEX_BUILDER_HOME% is the installation directory for Flex/Flash Builder
   - Requires elevation on Windows Vista/7
   - The version number may not match the above
2. Search for `com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.navigate` and comment out (or remove) the entire `<actionSet> ... </actionSet>` node that contains it
3. Save the file
4. Run `%FLEX_BUILDER_EXE -clean`

   - %FLEX_BUILDER_EXE% is FlexBuilder.exe or FlashBuilder.exe, depending on your version